# Plotly Histogram Percent over All traces

Tags: python, plotly

Having a Plot with 2 Histogramm traces like:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Histogram(
        x=df_A["col"],
        histnorm='percent',
        name="Trace_1",
        marker_color = "blue",
        xbins=dict( # bins used for histogram
            start=0.0,
            end=100,
            size=1
        ),
        bingroup=1,
    ),
    go.Histogram(
        x=df_B["col"],
        histnorm='percent',
        name="Trace_2",
        marker_color = "orange",
        xbins=dict( # bins used for histogram
            start=0.0,
            end=100,
            size=1
        ),
        bingroup=1,
    ),
])
```

The output is a percentage distribution over "Trace_1" and "Trace_2" separately, such that the sum of percentage of Trace_1 is 100% and the sum of percentage of Trace_2 is 100%.

How can I achieve a percentage distribution over both traces, meaning, that the sum of percentage over Trace_1 + Trace_2 = 100%?